# How to append a div into a div with variables Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this div here:

```
<div id='suggested_students'>

</div>
```

I am trying to write some javascript which will append this with the correct values:

```
<div id='STUDENT NAME' onClick='moveProfile("STUDENT NAME", "STUDENT ID")'>
STUDENT NAME<br>
STUDENT ID<br>
</div>
```

This is the javascript/ajax I have:

```
$('#search_bar').keyup(function () {

    var keyword = $('#search_bar').val();
    if(keyword.length > 2){
        console.log('hey')
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: {
            'keyword': keyword,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var suggestions = data.students;
                for(i = 0; i< suggestions.length; i++){
                    var current_student = suggestions[i];
                    console.log(current_student[0])
                    console.log(current_student[1])

                }
            }
            });
    }
})
```

and each iteration of the for loops produces something like:

`[STUDENT NAME, STUDENT ID`

How do I go about filling in these place holders and then appending the html to the main div for each student.

Comment: Are you asking what the http://api.jquery.com/append/ function is?

Comment: @freedomn-m no I need to know how to get the values from the list into the html and then append it

Comment: Just as an aside, ids can't have a space in them and they can't be duplicated so you are going to have to hope that every student has a unique name

Comment: I asked, because you've got this far, and the next step is some very basic string concatenation then `.append()` - so it's not / wasn't clear exactly what you were having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the student information into the container div for you...

```
success: function (data) {

    // get a reference to the container div
    var $container = $("#suggested_students");

    // remove any existing student information
    $container.empty(); 

    var suggestions = data.students;

    for(i = 0; i< suggestions.length; i++){

        var current_student = suggestions[i];

        // create a new div to add to the container element    
        var $div = $("<div/>");

        $div.data("name", current_student[0]);
        $div.data("id", current_student[1]);

        $div.html(current_student[0] + "<br/>" + current_student[1]);

        $div.on("click", moveProfile);

        $container.append($div);
    }
}
```

There's a couple of things worth noting here.  Firstly, I didn't give each new div the ID of the student name.  There are several reasons for this, but the main one is that it's not a very friendly ID.  Names have spaces and can also have other punctuation marks.  Also, you can have multiple students with the same name, but you can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Secondly, I set data attributes for each student div, rather than pass the values in an inline event handler.  To handle the click event you'd need this extra function, already referenced above...

```
function moveProfile() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var studentId = $this.data("id");
    var studentName = $this.data("name");

    // do whatever you need with the student info here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#search_bar').keyup(function () {
    var keyword = $(this).val(), $suggested_students;
    $suggested_students = $('#suggested_students');

    if (keyword.length > 2) {
            var url = window.location.pathname;
            $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'keyword': keyword
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var i, suggestions, s_name, s_id, current_student;

                suggestions = data.students;
                // empty before
                $suggested_students.empty();
                for(i = 0; i< suggestions.length; i++){
                    current_student = suggestions[i];
                    s_id = current_student[0];
                    s_name = current_student[1]
                    $suggested_students.append(
                        "<div id='" + s_id + "' onClick='moveProfile(\"" + s_name + "\", \"" + s_id +"\")'>" +
                            s_id +  " <br>" +
                            s_name + " <br>" +
                        "</div>"
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I suggest, however, to abort the `$.ajax` call in case a new string is written or wait a few moments before executing a new one and avoid using `onClick` in this way: just add a class or a selector like `#suggested_students > div` and add a `click` event listener to each `div` inside the container.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i = 0; i< suggestions.length; i++){
    var current_student = suggestions[i];
    console.log(current_student[0])
    console.log(current_student[1])
    var div = "<div id='"+current_student[0]+"' onClick='moveProfile(\""+current_student[0]+"\", "+current_student[1]+")'>"+current_student[0]+"<br>"+current_student[1]+"<br></div>";
    $('#suggested_students').append(div);
}
```